Who Instructed Pradyumna in the secrets of the ChakraVyuha?
In the following conversation, the words of Yudhishthira indicate that Pradyumna has complete mastery of the ChakraVyuha.

Addressing Abhimanyu, that slayer of hostile heroes, who was not
inferior to Vasudeva himself and whose energy was superior to that of
Arjuna, the king said, 'O child, act in such a way that Arjuna,
returning (from the Samsaptakas), may not reprove us. We do not know
how to break the circular array. Thyself, or Arjuna or Krishna, or
Pradyumna, can pierce that array. O mighty-armed one, no fifth person
can be found (to achieve that teat). O child, it behoveth thee, O
Abhimanyu, to grant the boon that thy sires, thy maternal uncles, and
all these troops ask of thee. Taking up thy arms quickly, destroy this
array of Drona, else Arjuna, returning from the fight, will reprove us
all.'
"Abhimanyu said, 'Desiring victory to my sires, soon shall I in battle
penetrate into that firm, fierce and foremost of arrays formed by
Drona. I have been taught by my father the method of (penetrating
and) smiting this kind of array. I shall not be able, however, to come
out if any kind of danger overtakes me.'
[Section 33, Abhimanyu-badha Parva, Drona Parva, The Mahabharata]

I want to know who taught the ChakraVyuha to Pradyumna. Who was Pradyumna's guru in mastering the ChakraVyuha?
